# jQuery plugin for rails application images not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, raty

I'm using the jQuery plugin [Raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty) for my ruby on rails 4.0 application and it seems to be working except the images for the stars aren't loading onto the screen.

[image]

So those images should be stars ^ When I mouseover them in the console while running web brick the following is outputted. (My scaffold is called reviews)

> Started GET "/reviews/star-off.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-28 14:15:42 -0400
>   Processing by ReviewsController#show as PNG
>     Parameters: {"id"=>"star-off"}
>     Review Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "star-off"]]
>   Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms
>     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Review with id=star-off):
>     app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:67:in `set_review'

I currently have the star images in apps/assets/javascripts/images but have also tried to put them in app/assets/images and app/views/reviews but they still won't show up. Is my issue that they aren't in the correct directory (and if so, which directory should they be in) or do I need to add some code manually to my reviews controller? Thanks.

edit: So when I try to use it in my index page, I only get an error saying this, so I must have to do something to my routes.rb file?

> ActionController::RoutingError (NNo route matches [GET] "/star-off.png")

edit: as requested here is routes.rb

```
ConcertReview::Application.routes.draw do
resources :reviews

get "review/index"
get "review/artist"
get "review/date"
get "review/venue"
get "review/genre"
get "review/comments"

root 'reviews#index'

get 'reviews/' => 'reviews#index'
end
```

and here's reviews_controller.rb (autogenerated from scaffold and have not modified)

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reviews
  # GET /reviews.json
  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
  end

  # GET /reviews/1
  # GET /reviews/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /reviews/new
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  # GET /reviews/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reviews
  # POST /reviews.json
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save
        format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/1
  # DELETE /reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reviews_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:artist, :venue, :date, :genre, :sound, :stagePresence, :songSelection, :overallRating, :comments)
    end
end
```

Comment: instead `id` you are trying to send `name`? show `reviews_controller` and `routes.rb` please

Comment: @Monk_Code I edited original post to include them.

Comment: try put you image in `app/assets/images/reviews`

Comment: that directory didn't exist so I made it and put the images there but still the same error message @Monk_Code

Comment: edited again, appears it might be a routing issue because that's the only error I get when I try to use the plugin in my index page.

Answer (score 0):

I had that very same problem on my project. The star images do belong in app/assets/images like you tried. However, you need to pass raty a **path option** like such:

```
$('div').raty({
  readOnly: true,
  halfScore: true,
  score: 3, 
  path: '/assets'
});
```

This is working for me.

Also, if you have turbolinks on, you're going to have to tweek any $(document).ready(function () {...}); you might have. That was the problem I had right after this one.